# Bootstrap 3 Button with Margin no longer working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, margin

[The fiddle for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kylebellamy/17wym13m/)

Can't figure out why this button doesn't rollover or is clickable when I add margin to the top and left. If I take out the class on line 47 of the css, it works as needed but trying to line it up with the text in the other column and it stops working.

EDIT: The button works when the screen is compressed, just not when in desktop width.

Using latest Bootstrap, jQuery.

Any thoughts?

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body { font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif; }
  a:link { text-decoration:none; color:rgba(0,0,0,1.00); }
  a:visited { text-decoration:none; color:rgba(0,0,0,1.00); }
  a:hover { text-decoration:none; color:rgba(0,0,0,1.00); }
  a:active { text-decoration:none; color:rgba(0,0,0,1.00); }

  .buttonsSub { font-size:20px; text-align:center; padding:5px; }
  h1 { font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:400; }

  .col-centered{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 3%;
    padding-left:-20px;
}

  .subTitle {font-size:30px; font-weight:400; }

  .border {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.border::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  transition: box-shadow .1s ease;
}
.border:hover::after {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.containerText {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#moveDown {margin-top: 20px;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row clearfix text-center">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <div id="moveDown"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style="width:60px; ">Back</a></div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 column col-centered">

        <h1 class="begining">title text</h1>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column text-center">
            <br><span class=" subTitle">Page Title</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 column text-centered" style="margin-top:30px; text-align:right">
        set one<br>
        <div class="border">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-300-10.jpg" alt="">
</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 column text-centered" style="margin-top:30px; text-align:left">
        set two<br>
        <div class="border">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-300-10.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 column text-centered" style="margin-top:30px; text-align:right">
        set three<br>
        <div class="border">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-300-10.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 column text-centered" style="margin-top:30px; text-align:left">
        set four<br>
        <div class="border">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-300-10.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 column text-centered" style="margin-top:30px; text-align:right">
        set five<br>
        <div class="border">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-300-10.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 column text-centered" style="margin-top:30px; text-align:left">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- End Content -->    
</div>
```

Comment: Ummm....which button isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `col-centered` class is very problematic.

```
.col-centered{
   float: none;
   margin: 0 3%;
   padding-left:-20px;
 }
```

You cannot have `float:none` on the same div as a column in Bootstrap as it will break the column alignment. In addition you cannot have a margin on the same div that has any `col-*-*` or else it will break the Bootstrap 12 column grid system. If you need the margin have another div inside the column div. Lastly you cannot have negative padding in any element as far as I know, thus the invalid attribute value.

**Edit:** As mentioned below, simply remove the class.

Comment: basically just remove the class `.col-centered` from the title div.

Comment: Vlad he is already doing the text-center class. He has everything he needs he just needs to remove .col-centered